# Foursquare venue added with api not showing up on userless search

Tags: api, foursquare

I've added a foursquare venue via the api attached to my access token. I've included all the proper fields, name, city, ll, etc. and it shows up as the first result when I search for the venue based on the `ll` param when using my authenticated api. However, if I search with an api attached to another access token, or do a userless search, it doesn't show up in that result set. It will show up though if I add a `query` param and search for the name.

Am I missing something about how I am supposed to create the venue, like some sort of make_public flag? I'd like to be able to create a venue tagged with an `ll` and then have it show up when that same `ll` param is passed into any sort of api, authenticated and not. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this venue a "home" venue?

Answer (score 1):

Is this venue a "home" venue? If so, see http://blog.foursquare.com/2011/09/29/making-your-house-into-a-home/ which talks about some of obfuscating foursquare does around home venues which would explain your observed behavior

**Update:**
Since the venue you added has 0 check-ins, it's considered a low-quality venue and is bypassed in favor of higher quality results that are nearby. The reason it's returned for the authoring user is because we consider it high-relevance for that user. All other users will probably need to specifically search for the venue before they will see it (as the venue acquires check-ins/activity, it may organically start appearing for query-less searches). For example, if I search for "library" at that location, I get your result back: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D37.7754738,-122.39986550000003%26query%3Dlibrary

Comment: oh man, you're awesome. that sounds exactly like what it is. i'll test it and let you know, but given that it was my home address that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: no luck. I tried it with an office and bar location and it still didn't work. Tried not including address, still didn't work. I did notice that home addresses i added a few days ago were categorized as "Home" today. I don't know if foursquare has some delay before making a location publicly searchable.

Comment: Ah, yes, there's an indexing delay before new venues become searchable.

Comment: I see that indexing delay when adding a venue and then searching with my user authenticated access token, it takes a few minutes before the new venue shows up. But its been several hours and I still don't see it coming up under a userless or another user authenticated api. Is there a delay for this as well? If so, do you know how long?

Comment: https://foursquare.com/v/eb-library-dev-party/4ffc73a1e4b07ec1036b3eca

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D37.7754738,-122.39986550000003

if i run that with the user that added the location, it is the first result, which is correct. if i run that with any other user, it doesn't show up.

Comment: any results from the venue id?

Comment: to find a specific venue, use /venues/search. /venues/explore gives you "recommended" venues and has a very strong personalization bias

Comment: The link I referenced was the "explore" section of foursquare's api docs, not the explore api method. If you click the link, the method is "venues/search" and from what I can tell, only the authenticated api I used to add the venue shows it as a result of "venues/search". I can find it if I query by name as well as longitude and latitude, but I'd like to add public venues, searchable only with longitude and latitude. Unless you can prove otherwise, I don't think this is possible to add a venue and then search for it with a userless api, or any other api than the one that added it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread it. As I said before, venues with zero check-ins are going to be ranked much lower than venues with active engagement. If a venue is missing, we expect users will search for it (via the query param) and find the new venue, but we will bias results towards place of higher known quality.